# How to use facebook sdk on a cocos2dx-project

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm doing a game cocos2d-x, when user gets a high score, I want them to touch on the Facebook icon and share the high score on their Facebook account timeline.

tutorials on facebook.developer.com using for objective-c project

Can anybody help me:(

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/feed/
 Have you checked the official Facebook tutorials?

Comment: this is for ios game with objective-c, not for cocos2d-x game with c++

Comment: Anybody help me:(

Answer (score 1):

The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is based completely on HTTP requests and JSON encoded data. Therefore all you have to do is be able to do HTTP requests and encode/decode JSON and you're set.

For HTTP, you can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

For JSON there's a lot of libraries, so be sure you check the ones at the bottom of its [official webpage](http://www.json.org/). I've used [libjson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/) and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/hiepnd/Screw. It comes with rich functionalities and detailed document.

Comment: This is a link only answer, we generally want answers to describe how to solve the issue rather than just a link as the link could break in the future. Are you able to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [HERE](https://github.com/Piperoman/CCSocialNetwork). Actually it works on iOS but is not working in Android.

You can follow the forum´s post [HERE](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12492?r=26311#message-26311)